# Copy C multi-dimensional array

Tags: c, arrays

Let say I have a multi-dimensional array like

```
int a[10][10]
int b[10][10]

void arrayCopy(int* a, int* b, int size){
    memcpy(b, a, size);
}

int main(){
   a[0][0] = 13;
   a[0][1] = 17;
   "and so on..."

   arraycopy(&a[0][0], &b[0][0], 10);
}
```

This code is not working I am unable to copy all the values from a -> b, where am I doing wrong??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is in the size. `sizeof(a)` is `100*sizeof(int)`, and you should pass that number.

(Your code copies `10 bytes`, when you want to copy `100 ints`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but can I get an explaination on why the size is multipled by 100?? Edit: thank you I wrote before explaination

Answer (score 4):

Your `size` argument is wrong for a few reasons. First of all, there are 10 * 10 == 100 elements, plus you're passing it to `memcpy()` which takes its size in *bytes* and your `int` is probably more like 4 bytes. Further, it's not really necessary to write such a function. This ought to suffice:

```
memcpy(b, a, sizeof(a));
```

Comment: The looping in the code above is done by `memcpy()`. It just makes a byte-for-byte copy of your one array into the other, so no further code is necessary. `sizeof(a) == sizeof(int)*10*10`

Comment: Thank you for the answer just tested the way to say, it works and I understand what you and asaelr mean :) thank you